# How to degrade Ionic v 2.2.3 to ionic v1.6 or below that

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic v 2.2.3. I have to work on Ionic v1.6. I have tried to uninstall ionic v 2.2.3, cordova and cleared caches then installed ionic by $ npm install ionic --v1.6, it still installs the newer version. Is there any method to get the older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to install a specific version of package from npm is `packagename@version`.

Try:

```
npm install -g ionic@1.6.0
```

if you want to install older version of ionic cli.

Comment: Thanks bro it helped